# Text shadow in porition of text/label xul xbl

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, xbl

I have a list of a bunch of names. As a user types I want to highlight the text matches in the names. (aside: if nothing is found i show "No matches for 'rar'").

This is my goal graphic mockup:

[image]

The user has typed "rar" and it has given the matched "rar"s in the names a red outline. I can accomplish this on the whole label with `text-shadow: 0 0 1px red` but i am not able to do on portion.

I've seen content editable divs http://html5demos.com/contenteditable
accomplish this. They can give different font colors to ranges. The xul label i can replace with xbl html textbox etc. I just can't figure it out though.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> They can give different font colors to ranges.

Those ranges essentially get wrapped into spans or font elements and those get styled. You can probably accomplish splitting text nodes by creating a [`Range()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range), setting its start and end inside the text node and then using [`range.surroundContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.surroundContents) to wrap it in a temporary node to style.

Once you don't need the text shadow anymore you can unwrap the text (by simply replacing the wrapper with its content) and [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize) the text nodes to restore the original state.

Maybe there is some way to magically create anonymous boxes (such as CSS uses internally for line boxes for example) but I don't know enough to point you in the right direction for that approach.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll play with and if I get it to work Ill come back and share. Ill leave this unaccepted in case anyone has a copy paste example to share for the time being. Thanks this helps a lot. :) So these range functions can be used on xul?

Comment: They're generic DOM apis. XUL is XML and supports DOM. At least in theory, I haven't tested it myself.